# Android MediaPlayer video seekTo not updating preview

Tags: android, video, media-player

I need to seek video file and see view frame that I've been seeking to.
I use default Andoid MediaPlayer class. Playback works fine, but when I try calling seekTo method, my Surface view remains unchanges, with 1st frame.

Here is my code:

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(offset);
mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                    Log.w("mediaPlayer", "onSeekComplete" );
                }
});
```

I've double offset value - it is exactly as I need.
Callback works - I see messages in logcat.

But picture in my SurfaceView remains the same regardless of offset value.

I have tried starting and pausing playback when onSeekComplete is fired. But it lead to nothing..

```
mediaPlayer.seekTo(offset);
mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    Log.w("mediaPlayer", "onSeekComplete" );
                }
});
```

If I call mediaPlayer.start(); playback starts with no problems.

Comment: it might be a different problem that you're facing but to my sadness I found out on my last project that the MediaPlayer only seeksTo 1 second intervals, smaller offsets it does nothing.

Comment: actually seekingTo less than 1 sec is possible in my situation. How did you solve this issue?

Comment: I still didn't, just found it out today. I tested by calling seekTo() with values varying 10msec at a time but it would only change on each second. Maybe it has to do with the video format, which format are you using? But on my case, considering that the app is already using the FFMPEG library, I might just generate video frames from it or completely remove the VideoView in favour of a ffmpegVideoView.